# Javascript event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a simple Pong game in Javascript. I have a Pong class, and I'd like to create a method to move the player rectangles based on how the mouse moves:

```
class Player 
{
  constructor()
  {
   // do stuff
  }
}

class Pong
{
  constructor(canvas)
  {
   //do stuff
   this.player1 = new Player(true); // Create an instance of another class

  }

  handleMouseMove(event)
  {
    var y = event.clientY;

    // this.player1 is undefined!!
    console.log("this.player1: "+this.player1);
    this.player1.pos.y = y;
  }


function main()
{
  // Initialize canvas and context
  canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  const pong = new Pong(canvas);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pong.handleMouseMove);
}
```

Whenever I start moving the mouse, it tells me that player1 is undefined. How can I set the class method as the event listener and have it know about the class' members?

Comment: Where is your `Player` class?

Comment: The Player class is outside of the Pong class, but in the same file. I'll edit my question to show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `this` inside the event listener refer the the element that fired the event (the canvas). You can bind the `this` keyword using [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pong.handleMouseMove.bind(pong));
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`bind` will return a function that its `this` keyword set to whatever you gave it as parameter.

Comment: it's not `this`, it's `pong`

Comment: @ChemicalRocketeer yeah I just noticed! I thought `main` was inside the class `Pong`!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the worst parts of javascript, in my opinion. When you pass `pong.handleMouseMove` to `addEventListener`, you are passing the function itself. In that context, when the event fires, it is calling the function outside the context of your `Pong` instance. You need to call [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on `handleMouseMove`, like so:

`canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pong.handleMouseMove.bind(pong));`

`bind` exists on all functions, and returns a new function which you can pass around, and ensures that `this` inside the function is bound to the specified parameter (in this case, `pong`).

edit: The other answer by ibrahim mahrir is wrong, you have to pass your `pong` instance to the `bind` function. Whatever you pass is what `this` will be assigned to inside the function you are binding.

Comment: you can also `canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) { pong.handleMouseMove(e); })` - not as nice, but very common

Comment: I see...I appreciate the explanation. I accepted the other answer because it was closer to the top (and fixed by the time I saw it). Thanks!!